# Trying to print a label from IIS to printer but having no luck

Tags: c#, iis, printing

I have code in visual studio and when i run it from visual studio i can print no problem. as soon as i put the code into IIS I cant print to the barcode printer. the printer is located on another machine in the office.

I have tried putting the AppPool in and granting it permissions to the printer but the other computer doesn't recognize the AppPool. The printer is being shared and i can print to it off of any computer in the office.

```
else if (e.CommandName == "Print")
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                int id = 
Convert.ToInt32(grdList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
                try
                {
                    outerboxbc o = new outerboxbc();
                    o = oDL.Get_Outerboxbc(id);

                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

                    pd.PrintPage += new 
PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                    this.ob_Barcode.Text = 
o.barcode.bc_Barcode.ToString();
                    // pd.PrintPage += (print, args) => 
pd_PrintPage(items, id, args);
                    // Set the printer name. 
                    // pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\NS5\hpoffice
                    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = 
                    "\\\\ALPHAPC08\\ZDesigner GK420d";

                    pd.Print();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void pd_PrintPage(object print, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        long de_RecordID = Convert.ToInt32(this.de_RecordID.Value);
        cDelivery d = new cDelivery();
        d = oDL.get_cDelivery(de_RecordID);


        Font printFont = new Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 24);
        Font printFont1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

        SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString("*" + this.ob_Barcode.Text + "*", 
        printFont, br, 10, 85);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(d.de_ProjectNumber, printFont1, br, 110, 
        150);
    }
```

Above is the code i use. It works fine in Visual studio and prints only doesn't work when i put it up as a live website in IIS.

Comment: Does the printer allow printing using the credentials of the user the IIS application pool runs under? If the code prints fine in a desktop app or Cassini, you should review what differences are between a IIS and the Visual Studio, and the most important one is the user it is running it.

Comment: thanks @bradbury9 I wil lhave a look at that. I have allowed "everyone" access to the printer in the permissions and i also removed username and password protection for the pc which the printer is set up on.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3